# How to update the website && the mobile from another process in node js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have some process:

```
var fetcher = new Fetcher({ url: 'http://www.example.com' });
setInterval(function() {
    fetcher.getImageUrls().then(saveToDb, handleError, notifyProgress);
}, 10000);
```

I also have a website, I want to use socket.io for pushing updates
about the progress (using the notifyProgress method). I don't know
how to sync the website with the process.

note that i can't use events because the process can live anywhere (i can also duplicate the process with more instances)

How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Redis to create a PUB/SUB system.

You will publish to the channel your updates;

```
// notifyProgress.js
var Redis = require('redis'),
    redis = Redis.createClient(6379, 127.0.0.1);

module.exports.publish = function (req, res, next) {
    //publish to the mySpecialChannel channel.
    redis.publish('mySpecialChannel', data);
};
```

your different servers/clusters will subscribe to the channel.

```
//socket server
var Redis = require('redis'),
    redis = Redis.createClient(6379, 127.0.0.1),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

redis.on('subscribe', function (channel, count) {
    console.log('server subscribed to %s', channel);
});

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    if (channel === 'mySpecialChannel') {
        //send info to your clients.
        io.emit('update', message)
    }
});

redis.subscribe('mySpecialChannel');
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please select this as the answer.